# Forcing failure of a Kiwi test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, kiwi

Is there a way to force failure in a Kiwi test, i.e. the equivalent of XCTFail().

I can write something like

```
[@"" should] beNil]
```

that will always fail but I was figuring Kiwi must have something a little more expressive of the developer's intent baked into the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can use the `fail()` macro:

```
fail(@"message");
```